# How to calculate the sample size when compare rate using Poisson regression?

Tags: r, statistical-power, poisson-regression, sas

I have a question regarding the sample size calculation if I want to compare rates using Poisson regression. I want to compare the rate of book A to the rate of book B. The rate of book A is defined as "number of the bookstores that have the book A"/"number of the people need book A in that city" , and the rate of book B is defined as "number of the bookstores that have book B"/"number of the people need book B in that city". And the cities are more than 10, which means, I need to know the rate of book A and rate of book B of each city.

I am little bit confused, if I need to conduct a power analysis to find out the sample size for this study, what sample size is it for this study? Is it the overall bookstore in that city(need to select specific number of bookstores, and find out how many bookstores have book A/B)? Or is it the number of bookstores that have book A/B? Is it the number of people that need book A/B? Or is it the rate of book A or book B?

Is power analysis necessary in this study? If so, since it's rate comparison, I think the Poisson regression is appropriate, how should I do it? I can use SAS or R. Can anyone help me with it? Hopefully that I express myself clearly. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of data will you collect?  How might they differ, if at all, from what a complete and perfectly accurate census of the bookstores and people would yield?

Comment: Do you sample all of the bookstores in a city, or only a sample of bookstores in a city?

Comment: Yeah, that's my question, since the people who need book A/B are fixed, if I want to compare "the # of bookstores that have book A"/"# of people that need book A" 
 to "the # of bookstores that have book B"/"# of people that need book B", should I sample all of the bookstores in a city or only a sample of bookstores in a city? If only a sample of bookstores in a city, can I do a power analysis based on that?

Comment: How do you find out the numbers of people who need a book?

Comment: It's just an example, actually the number is some kind of incidence that related to A and I can find it through some reports

Comment: That detail is relevant because those numbers are likely known only very imprecisely and the level of imprecision is key to the computation of sample size.